# Why is my boot-loader crashing on far jump into protected mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev

I have trying to boot into a kernel made in C. I have been learning and attempting to make a functional boot loader for a while now, however it always fails in one spot or another. I am using the gnu assembler "as" to assemble this file, however I am using `.intel_syntax` to reverse the instruction format to the intel one I am used to. Everything seems to work fine up until I make the far jump into 32bit code (`jmp CODE_SEG:init_32`). Here is the bootloader:

```
.intel_syntax

.extern kernel_entry
.globl _start

.macro printstat a
    push %ax
    mov %ah, 0x0e
    mov %al, \a
    int 0x10
    pop %ax
.endm

.macro printdblstat a, b
    push %ax
    mov %ah, 0x0e
    mov %al, \a
    int 0x10
    mov %al, \b
    int 0x10
    pop %ax
.endm 

.code16
.section .text
 
.extern kernel_entry
KERNEL_ADDRESS = kernel_entry
STACK = 0x9000

_start: 
mov drive, %dl

# setup stack
mov %bp, STACK 
mov %sp, %bp

call load_drive
jmp GDT_init

# ;;;;;;;;;; Drive loader ;;;;;;;;;;
load_drive:
    mov %al, 2  # read number of sectors (2)
    mov %ah, 0x02 # read mode

    mov %cl, 0x02 # start from sector 2 (sector 1 is boot sector)
    mov %ch, 0x00 # cylinder 0
    mov %dl, drive
    mov %dh, 0x00 # head 0

    # dl = drive number is set as input to disk_load
    # es:bx = buffer pointer is set as input as well
 
    mov %bx, 0x1000 # load into addr
    int 0x13      # BIOS interrupt (read disk)
    jc disk_error # check carry bit for error
    
    mov %dl, drive     # disk
    cmp %al, 2 # read 2 sectors?
    ret

    # sector error
    mov %bl, %al
    printstat %bl
    printdblstat 'E', '1'
    jmp .

    # disk error
    disk_error:
    printdblstat 'E', '2'
    jmp .

# ;;;;

# ;;;;;;;;;;; GDT ;;;;;;;;;;;;
.section .data
.align 8
drive: .byte 0 

gdt_start: 
    .4byte 0x0,0x0
gdt_code:
    .byte 0xFF,0xFF,0x0,0x0,0x0,0b10011010,0b11001111,0x0
gdt_data:
    .byte 0xFF,0xFF,0x0,0x0,0x0,0b10010010,0b11001111,0x0
gdt_video:
    .byte 0xFF,0xFF,0x0,0x80,0x0B,0b10010010,0b01000000,0x0
gdt_end:
gdt_descriptor:
    .word gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 # size (16 bit)
    .4byte gdt_start # address (32 bit)
CODE_SEG = gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG = gdt_data - gdt_start
VIDEO_SEG = gdt_video - gdt_start
.section .text

# ;;;;;;;;;; Init GDT ;;;;;;;;;;
GDT_init:  
    lgdt gdt_descriptor
    
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ds, %ax
    mov %ss, %ax

    in %al,0x70
    or %al,0x80
    out 0x70, %al # nonmasked interrupts
    
    in %al,0x92
    or %al,2
    out 0x92, %al # A20 line

    cli 

    mov %eax, %cr0
    or %al, 0x1 # protected mode
    mov %cr0, %eax

    jmp CODE_SEG:init_32 # <================================== crashes here

# ;;;;;;;;;;; 32 bit mode ;;;;;;;;;;
.code32
.align 32
init_32:
    mov %ax, DATA_SEG
    mov %ds, %ax
    mov %ss, %ax
    mov %es, %ax
    mov %fs, %ax
    mov %gs, %ax

    mov %ebp, STACK
    mov %esp, %ebp

    call kernel_entry
    hlt

.space 510-(.-_start)
.word 0xAA55 # magic number
```

When I link it with my kernel and run it in qemu using the `-d cpu-reset` logging flag, this comes out

```
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000663
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000000
EIP=0000fff0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
CS =f000 ffff0000 0000ffff 00009b00
SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
FS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
GS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 0000ffff
IDT=     00000000 0000ffff
CR0=60000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=DYNAMIC
EFER=0000000000000000
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM01=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM02=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM03=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM04=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM05=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM06=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM07=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Triple fault
```

Additionally, when logging using `-d int`, it would display this:

```
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     1: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0000:00007c70 pc=00007c70 SP=0000:00009000 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000011
EAX=00000011 EBX=00001000 ECX=00000002 EDX=00000080
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00009000 ESP=00009000
EIP=00007c70 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300 DPL=0 DS16 [-WA]
CS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009b00 DPL=0 CS16 [-RA]
SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300 DPL=0 DS16 [-WA]
DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300 DPL=0 DS16 [-WA]
FS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300 DPL=0 DS16 [-WA]
GS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300 DPL=0 DS16 [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000002 CCD=00000011 CCO=LOGICB
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
```

Looking at the CPU fault `0xd`, it is telling me I have some sort of general protection fault, and then double faults? Does this mean my GDT has been set up incorrectly, or what else could it be? I am really confused and any help would be really appreciated.

If it is any help, I am compiling with this instruction, and booting from `final.bin`

```
gcc -Wl,--oformat=binary -Wl,\
-Ttext=0x7c00 -Wl,--build-id=none -Wl,-melf_i386 \
-nostartfiles -nostdlib -fno-pie -O0 -ffreestanding \
-m32 -o /tmp/lima/final.bin bootloader/boot.s kernel/entry.c
```

Comment: The way you build without a proper linker script (and relying on `-Ttext=0x7c00`) may be causing unexpected issues with where sections are placed in `final.bin` . Can you tell me the size of your `final.bin`?

Comment: You are also loading the kernel to es:0x1000 (without setting ES - and ES should be 0 the way you are doing it)) but because you are linking everything without a linker script the bootloader and the kernel have an origin (ORG) at memory address 0x7c00. You can't load the kernel at 0x1000. You'd have to set BX to 0x7e00 to read the sectors into memory right after the bootloader in memory for that to work.

Comment: If your `final.bin` is quite large (much larger than 1k) than you likely have `.eh_frame` sections in your `final.bin` bloating its size. If so you'll want to consider adding the option   `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` to your GCC command line. You will also have to make sure you read enough sectors in memory to load the entire kernel. As it is you only load 2 sectors (and you may need more depending on `final.bin` size)

Comment: It may be much easier if you separate your bootloader from your kernel and builds separate binaries for both. Then just concatenate them together to build a disk image.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you for your reply, my file is 9Kib (9256 to be exact). However it is mostly empty after 1.1kib.

Comment: I bet it shrinks considerable with the `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` option. I suspect it will end up a little over 1KiB. But then the problem arises you only read 2 sectors with this code (and may need more so `mov %al, 2  # read number of sectors (2)` may need to be changed as your kernel grows. That and ES needs to be set to zero and BX set to 0x7E00 instead of 0x1000.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I fixed my code to set register es to 0 prior to setting bx and changed it to 0x7e00, however it seems to be still crashing. I am just now looking at your third comment, and there is definitely something sketchy. Let me try to fix this and I will get back to you.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh my gosh.. you have no idea how long I have been working at this and how many frustrating nights haha. Thank you so much for your help! it works now.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You are also correct about the sectors. However, why I try changing it to say 3 or another number, I am getting a disk error? Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this.

Comment: Possibly because your kernel isn't more than 2 sectors and your binary is between 1.0KiB and 1.5KiB. QEMU may be trying to read beyond the end of the disk image you have and giving an error.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh that makes sense thank you. Final question sorry, when I declare a string in my kernel file, it seems to fault again? I get double fault again, but this time I am also getting exception `0xffffffff` along with `0xd`?

Comment: I have a recommendation. Same one I made earlier. Split the kernel and bootloader and build them separately. I was hinting at a more serious issue if you don't intend to use linker scripts. Your data and text sections are falling on different sides of the disk signature 0xaa55 and that's going to cause issues. Make a binary with the bootloader. Make a binary with the kernel and then put them together to form a disk image. You are going to have all ends of problems doing what you are doing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ok will do. Again, thanks for all your help! I will close this question now.

Comment: As for the string in the kernel file I bet you anything the size of your `final.bin` got a bit bigger and you aren't reading the string into memory? (not enough sectors read now maybe?). But yeah this is getting outside the scope of this question.